# Datetime type in Drupal 7 schema

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm writing a new Drupal 7 module (Drupal 7.10, Date 7.x-2.0-rc1 installed, Schema 7.x-1.0-beta3 installed)
i defined a table in mymodule.install:

```
$schema['museums_tickets']= array(
    'fields' => array(
        'nid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'day' => array(
        'type' => 'datetime', 
        'mysql_type' => 'DATETIME',
        'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'tickets' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
    'ticket_code' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 32,
            'not null' => TRUE, 
            'default' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('nid', 'day','ticket_code'),
);
```

but i obtain the following errors:

```
Field museums_tickets.day: no Schema type for mysql type datetime.
museums_tickets.day: no type for Schema type datetime.
Field museums_tickets.day: no Schema type for type datetime.
```

The same applies if i use

```
'type' => 'datetime:normal',
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem. 
I don't want to store dates as timestamp, since another person wrote a lot of code and obviously i don't want to rewrite all.
I already looked at [drupal 7 custom schema error datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170779/drupal-7-custom-schema-error-datetime) but the answer doesn't work.
Maybe i'm doing something wrong, but i don't find what.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look in the schema of the Date module you will find something like

```
'day' => array(
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
)
```

Actually the answer of Clive was the one i picked first but later gave me problems with the Views module.

This implementation of the Date module save my day

Answer (score 10):

The following works for me (Drupal 7.10):

```
'day' => array(
  'mysql_type' => 'DATETIME',
  'not null' => TRUE,
)
```

(notice the `mysql_type` key *instead of* `type`)

From the [Schema docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7):

> If you need to use a record type not included in the officially supported list of types above, you can specify a type for each database backend. In this case, you can leave out the type parameter

`datetime` is not an allowed generic type in Drupal 7 so leaving the `type` key in there will always cause an error.

Comment: I tried it in a new module, but it doesn't create the table when install it.

Comment: i tried it in drupal 7.17 but got error: no Schema type for mysql type datetime.

Answer (score 1):

The Date contrib module has:

```
function date_field_schema($field) {
  $db_columns = array();
  switch ($field['type']) {
    case 'datestamp':
      $db_columns['value'] = array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'sortable' => TRUE,
        'views' => TRUE,
      );
      break;

    case 'datetime':
      $db_columns['value'] = array(
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
        'pgsql_type' => 'timestamp without time zone',
        'sqlite_type' => 'varchar',
        'sqlsrv_type' => 'smalldatetime',
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'sortable' => TRUE,
        'views' => TRUE,
      );
      break;

    default:
      $db_columns['value'] = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 20,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'sortable' => TRUE,
        'views' => TRUE,
      );
      break;
  }
```